# checking if condition in stored procedure( sql server 2005)

Tags: sql-server-2005

i have  an SP where  i need  to  check  for   if condition

```
ALTER   PROCEDURE [dbo].[spCheck]  
 @strEmpname  VARCHAR(50),  
 @intReturn  INT OUTPUT,
 @intWorkdID  INT,
 @intEmpID INT  
AS  

BEGIN  
IF(@intWorkdID is not null and @intWorkdID != '')
    BEGIN 
      IF EXISTS ( SELECT *   
          FROM Employee   
         WHERE [Empname] = @strEmpname   
         AND WorkID = @intWorkdID 
           )  
       SELECT @intReturn = '1'  
    END 
ELSE    
IF(@intEmpID is not null and @intEmpID != '')
   BEGIN
     IF EXISTS ( SELECT * 
          FROM Employee   
         WHERE [Empname] = @strEmpname    
         AND PeopleID = @intEmpID 
           )  
       SELECT @intReturn = '1'   
    END
 ELSE IF(@intEmpID is not null and @intEmpID != '') 
 and(@intWorkdID is not null and @intWorkdID != '')
  BEGIN  
   SELECT @intReturn = '0'  
  END  

END
```

here  based on  WorkID,EmpID
1 condition  and  2  condition  should execute

if  both  condition   fail i need  to  excute the  third  condition

can  any one  tell the  syntax  for it

thanks

prince

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Best way is that you can use

Try something as below:

```
SELECT @intReturn = 
     CASE
          WHEN @intWorkdID IS NULL THEN 1
          WHEN @intWorkdID<>'' THEN 1
          WHEN @intEmpID IS NULL THEN 1
          WHEN @intEmpID <>'' THEN 1
          ELSE 0
     END
```

[Case... When](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx)

for this

Answer (score 2):

An `int` can't equal `''`.

I'm not sure what you're asking for in your logic, but when an `if` doesn't match then it runs the `else` part.  You can then have anpther `if -> else` after that as per your script.